# Step function - sqs - ecs

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions

We have a use case where all the micro services are on ECS and we are planning to implement Saga pattern with AWS Step Functions. AWS has below pattern which uses Lambda. Just want to know if it is a good solution (scalable, resilient etc) to use the same approach and replace Lambda's with ECS services? Please advise.

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/orchestrate-microservices-with-message-queues-on-step-functions/

Note : AWS Step Functions have integration with ECS tasks and due to various reasons we don't want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see issues with using SQS to trigger ECS.

However, what is the issue with using the Step Functions ECS integration to call your ECS directly?

You can define error handling and retries within the Step Functions, if that was something that might have been a blocker.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html